# MySQL perform check on unique column combinations

Tags: php, mysql

In a MySQL table there are the following columns:

```
id, spn(PK), cat1, cat2, cat3, act1, act2, act3
```

(cat fields are of VARCHAR type, act fields are INT) and I need to perform a check to see if the total of unique combinations of all catΧ fields is equal to the unique combinations of all actΧ fields and if not, return the list of spn values for the found mismatches.

My initial thought was to perform a selection of `concat(cat1,cat2,cat3) as A` as well as the `concat(act1,act2,act3) as B` and compare them but I'm not quite sure how to perform the comparison and return the list of found spn's where `A <> B`. Any ideas are welcome.

My app is in PHP so if you can suggest a solution using also PHP that's fine.

**NOTE:** Based on the first 2 answers, I'd like to clarify that i'm trying to check if the number of unique combinations of all cat fields is equal to that of the combination of act fields.

[Sample data](https://db.tt/9T50dEk7)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know column types, so I will go with the most standard solution:

```
SELECT spn
FROM table
WHERE cat1 != act1 || cat2 != act2 || cat3 != act3
```

Maybe your database design could be improved. Introducing number in column names is often synonym of *bad design*.

**EDIT:** Assuming order is not important in your permutation:

```
SELECT id
FROM files_imported
WHERE ((cat1 != cat2) + (cat1 != cat3) + (cat2 != cat3)) != ((act1 != act2) + (act1 != act3) + (act2 != act3))
```

Comment: I'm not after comparing each catX field to the equivalent actX field, but to check if the number of combinations of cat fields are equal to the number of act field combinations. As far as the structure, i didn't design the DB, I'm simply performing some data checks.

Comment: Then, I'm not sure to understand the check you want to perform. I think the `CONCAT` solution described in your question won't be better at *comparing the number of combinations*, though.

Comment: By concatenating the fields and grouping by the concatenated values, you get the number of unique combinations. It's the comparison of those combinations that I'm after.

Comment: I have edited my answer, still not sure... Please edit your question and provide a sample data set, along with your expected result.

Comment: I've written a query similar to yours, problem is, if t1!=t2, how do I find the rows for the fields that mismatch?

Comment: Since you are counting on all rows, I don't understand which are *fields that mismatch*. I have edited again.

Comment: The COMBINATIONS of the cat fields opposed to the COMBINATIONS of the act fields are those that matter to me, not their unique values.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39596/discussion-between-guillaume-poussel-and-bikey77)